# Pronunciation of boggling and similar *ing words

Tags: pronunciation, ing

Are there multiple valid pronunciations for *ing* or present participle form of boggle -- **[bog-uh l]** | **/ˈbɒg əl/**? I.e. are both of the following valid for boggling (not thinking of *bogglin* or other shortened pronunciations)?

1. **[bog-ling]** | **/ˈbɒg lɪŋ/**
2. **[bog-uh ling]** | **/ˈbɒg əlɪŋ/**

If the second form is valid, are there specific dialects where it's common? Otherwise, is there a term for this type of mispronunciation?

Comment: I don't think the second one is a 'mispronunciation'. It is a common alternative as correct as the first.

Comment: Uh, you're *supposed* to be boggled by it.

Comment: (Consider how you'd pronounce "bottling".)

Comment: @HotLicks that's partly a difference between AmE and BrE

Comment: @WillCrawford - It has a lot to do with whether the speaker makes an effort to speak distinctly or not -- some do, some don't, and some people vary, depending on the circumstances.   Like how many Rs are there in "February".

Answer (score 1):

[Epenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis) is the insertion of a consonant or vowel, usually to ease pronunciation, as in the p-sound most speakers use in *ham[p]ster*, or for those who find *thl* a bother to pronounce, the insertion of a schwa in *ath[e]lete.*

Now your particular case is somewhat different, since retaining a vowel otherwise elided is not the same as inserting it where it never was to begin with. It could be argued that in the present participles – or other derivatives such as agent nouns in *-er* – derived from verbs ending in *-le*, the elision is very common, but not mandatory. While most native speakers would pronounce *toddler* with the elision, *toddling* sounds more natural to me without it. At any rate, I don't think the non-elided form of such words is so deprecated that it would be considered an error. In other words, a matter of opinion.

A similar case is the tendency of some native speakers not to pronounce vocalic *n* in contractions such as *didn't, wouldn't,* or *couldn't*, instead inserting a schwa or lately even a fronted vowel before the *n*, or in words ending in *-ant* where vocalic *n* would otherwise be expected, like *important*. (Take that, Ezra Klein! See [this video at 1:40 mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNsI0MvEYfk&feature=youtu.be&t=1m40s)) While this particular pronunciation puts my teeth on edge, enough educated elites use it in their podcasts that calling it an error rather than a new variation seems ill-advised.

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean by “not to vocalize the _n_ in contractions…”. Do you mean they pronounce _didn’t_ as /ˡdɪdnət/? If so, can you provide an example? I don’t recall ever hearing/noticing that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: No, the schwa before the n: didunt. Edited to clarify. https://youtu.be/rNsI0MvEYfk at 1:40.

Comment: Oh, so you meant ‘vocalise’ as in ‘make syllabic’. It was the apostrophe bit that confused me, since seeing the apostrophe as a sign to add a schwa would imply adding the schwa _after_ the n. But there is no phonemic distinction between /n̩/ and /ən/ anyway, so it shouldn’t matter whether you say /ˡdɪdənt/ or /ˡdɪdn̩t/. Certainly, /ˡlɪtəl/ is common enough too, and has been for a long time.

Comment: I completely disagree with you. one can "sing through" a nasal liquid, and I would see the schwa there as epenthetic.

Comment: That doesn’t mean there’s a phonemic distinction—there isn’t. The schwa may be epenthetic, or the syllabic consonant may be due to the loss of a schwa (well, it definitely is ultimately, but I mean a preceding one here), but both variants exist, and I don’t think you’re right to call either a recent phenomenon. What I’m pretty sure **is** a recent phenomenon is pronouncing /n̩ ~ ən/ as [ɪn ~ in], with a raised, fronted vowel. (Not, as far as I can tell, what Ezra says in the video you linked to.)

Comment: Hmmm. 1) I am not used to educated speakers inserting a schwa into _n't_ contractions, but (2) I think you're right that sometimes Klein uses a front vowel instead of a schwa, which triggered my allergy.

Comment: Most *educated* speakers insert the *o* into the *n’t* contraction ;o)